# Check for system exit and for error logs with unittest in Python

Tags: python, logging, python-unittest

Is it possible to check if a program stopped with `sys.exit()` and check for the messages that were logged using the `logging` module?

For example, let's say I have the following function in a file called func.py:

```
import logging
import sys

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,format='%(levelname)s:%(message)s')

def my_func(word):
    if word == "orange":
        logging.info("All is good with {}.".format(word))
    elif word == "apple":
        logging.error("Something went wrong with {}.".format(word))
        sys.exit()
```

Now, I have created a couple of tests to check my function's performance. I know that, to test the messages logged--provided that the program completed its function--I can do something like this:

```
import unittest
from func import *

class Test_errors_and_messages(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_logs(self):
        with self.assertLogs() as captured:
            my_func("orange")
        self.assertEqual(len(captured.records), 1)
        self.assertEqual(captured.records[0].getMessage(), "All is good with orange.")
```

And if I want to check if the program is stopping when expected, I'm doing something similar to this:

```
import unittest
from func import *

class Test_errors_and_messages(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_exit(self):
        with self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
            my_func("apple")
```

My question is: is it possible to test for a system exit and the messages logged at the same time? In other words, I would like to modify the `test_exit()` test to check (a) that the program stopped with a `SystemExit` and (b) that the message

> Something went wrong with apple.

was logged. In particular, I want to check both of these conditions because in my real script, I have several conditions that will prompt `sys.exit()`, and I want to test that when the program stops, it is stopping for the reason that I expect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put the two context managers together:

```
with self.assertLogs() as captured, self.assertRaises(SystemExit):
    my_func("apple")
self.assertEqual(captured.output, ["INFO:foo:tasty"])
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Such an easy solution! Thanks.

Comment: anyone come to this answer: It is important, that the log assertion is on the same indentation-level as the with-statement: ` self.assertEqual(captured.output, ["ERROR:foo:xxx"])`

Comment: Right, it should not be inside the with block, because an exception would bump you out of the indented block before the assertion is reached.